# Set array value at specific index in ClickHouse

Tags: clickhouse

Is it possible to update an array at specific index in existing row in ClickHouse db? Something like `alter table mytable set arr[3]=8`

Comment: how often updates like this are occurred? Is it part of data business-logic or just single fix? Is it applied to full table, why not defined where-clause?

Comment: @vladimir, this will be part of business-logic (will happen pretty frequently) and of course there will be a where clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table xxx(A Int64, Person Nested (Name String, value String))
Engine=MergeTree order by A;

insert into xxx values (1, ['a','b','c'], ['aaa','bbb','ccc'])
```

if array index = 3 then name = '1'

```
alter table xxx update "Person.Name" = 
arrayMap( i-> if(i=3,'1',"Person.Name"[i]), arrayEnumerate("Person.Name")) where 1;

select *  from xxx;
┌─A─┬─Person.Name───┬─Person.value────────┐
│ 1 │ ['a','b','1'] │ ['aaa','bbb','ccc'] │
└───┴───────────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

if name = a then name = 1

```
alter table xxx update "Person.Name" = 
arrayMap( i-> if(i='a','1',i), "Person.Name") where 1;
    
select  * from xxx;
┌─A─┬─Person.Name───┬─Person.value────────┐
│ 1 │ ['1','b','c'] │ ['aaa','bbb','ccc'] │
└───┴───────────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

if name = c then value = 333

```
alter table xxx update "Person.value" = 
arrayMap( (i,j) -> if(j='c','333', i), "Person.value", "Person.Name") where 1;

 select  * from xxx

┌─A─┬─Person.Name───┬─Person.value────────┐
│ 1 │ ['1','b','c'] │ ['aaa','bbb','333'] │
└───┴───────────────┴─────────────────────┘
```